# Conflicting security messages about "chrome://settings" page; is it secure or not?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, chromium

Accessing the `chrome://settings` page, I see two things contradicting each other:

[image: chrome settings page]

- The ribbon below the address bar shows "You're viewing a secure Chromium Page."
- On the other hand, the security overview under the security tab in Chromium developer tools says "This Page is not secure".

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

1. Why these two conflicting messages ? Any vulnerability here?
2. Is the `chrome://settings` page really secure?
3. If not secure, does it impact the browser or anything like that?
4. What could be possible resolution?

EDIT : I want to clarify that my question is `Why these two conflicting security messages ?` and only after then the security stuff that is well answered by question that everybody just seems to mark this question a duplicate of :

[How do browsers make sure their settings page is secure ?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173685/how-do-browsers-make-sure-their-setting-page-is-secure)

So, please consider answering question 1 in the OP and then follow the rest.

If you still think the question is a duplicate, please read the answers below first and then compare it with answers given to the questions for which you think this question is a possible duplicate of.

Thanks.

Comment: Then it's one of two things: they assume anyone likely to use "developer tools" will know enough to realize that warning doesn't apply to built in settings pages, or they simply didn't consider it at all.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that `It's one of two things`. I want to know which one it is and how ? Could you please explain it in an answer ?

Comment: What do you mean secure? What kind of security do you expect from a built-in page?

Comment: I am clarifying it again that Question 1 in OP is the main question to ask. Rest of the questions 2,3,4 just covers the security side (If there is) of the phenomenon. So OP is not a duplicate of question being advised by @AndrolGenhald. Also, I cannot explain or edit my question furthermore , so please remove the duplicate question advise.

Comment: This question has been asked before, has it not?

Comment: @C0deDaedalus The `It's one of two things` referred here, is not the same as the two things you refer to. It's not between is secure or is not secure. Both of the "things" they mention are secure. It's an "in any case" argument

Comment: @MCMastery, My question is `Why these two conflicting messages` ( that's already very well answered by @arminius ) and after then the security stuff. If you think question has been asked before, then please point to that by a link in the comment. Also please read the answers and then compare to answers of the question already asked.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus I'm sorry, I just clearly remember a question asking about the Chrome settings security message in dev tools, but I can't find it... I must be going crazy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do browsers make sure their setting page is secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173685/how-do-browsers-make-sure-their-setting-page-is-secure)

Comment: @XiongChiamiov I already proposed the duplicate, but it was rejected by OP.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, your settings page is secure. What you're seeing is just an inconsistency on Chrome's side.

In the devtools, only valid HTTPS connections are labeled "secure". Other documents, including local files and settings pages, are shown as "not secure", even if they don't ever go through a network. The notion of a "secure connection" just doesn't apply to local resources. (A settings page is local, too.)

Why? Because the label is based on a site's [`SecurityState`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/dd960ac6d32ba89d28596cd09155a2f56ed72986/content/browser/devtools/protocol/security_handler.cc#32) which is set to "neutral" for plain HTTP sites, local files and settings pages alike. And a "neutral" security state is verbalized as "not secure":

```
const summaryExplanationStrings = {
  'unknown': Common.UIString('The security of this page is unknown.'),
  'insecure': Common.UIString('This page is not secure (broken HTTPS).'),
  'neutral': Common.UIString('This page is not secure.'),
  'secure': Common.UIString('This page is secure (valid HTTPS).')
};
```

[(Source)](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/dd960ac6d32ba89d28596cd09155a2f56ed72986/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/security/SecurityPanel.js#668)

In the address bar, however, Chrome has a special label for viewing an internal page:

```
<message name="IDS_PAGE_INFO_INTERNAL_PAGE" desc="Message to display in the page
 info bubble when the page you are on is a chrome:// page or about:something.">
    You are viewing a secure Google Chrome page.
</message>
```

[(Source)](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/dd960ac6d32ba89d28596cd09155a2f56ed72986/components/components_chromium_strings.grd#212)

Hence, the texts differ. Ultimately, the security indicators in the address bar should be your preferred means of verification. In other places, such as the devtools, the UI may be not as clear.

Comment: +1 for pointing to source code. How you found that ?

Comment: @C0deDaedalus Just grepped `You're viewing a secure Chromium page` in the Chromium source and looked where it's used.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus I usually search the [github](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=You%27re+viewing+a+secure+Chromium+page&type=)

Comment: @Arminius, as you have answered it very well, So you know the question very well. In that case can you please tell the community that the question is not a duplicate of [link everyone is pointing to](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173685/how-do-browsers-make-sure-their-setting-page-is-secure). I believe you have enough reputations for this.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus I think you have sufficiently clarified it yourself. Unless the question actually gets enough close votes, I think you're fine. If it actually gets closed, you can raise the problem on [meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/) and the community will help you resolve it.